# I need help generating random sku code in php language

Tags: php, function, random

I have this function but can't get the output like this.
Please help me to get this result RMXZ-MIGX-DYUJ-YVJM

```
function randomString()
{
    $characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randstring = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $randstring = $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters))];
    }
    return $randstring;
}
echo randomString(); // output: A or B or ....Z
```

Thank you very much

Comment: What _do_ you get as output? Should the output contain only uppercase letters? (If so, why use numbers and lowercase in your `$characters`?) Why should `$i` be `< 10`? Are you aware that you're overwriting `$randstring` on every iteration with `$randstring =...`?

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected the question, can you help me

Comment: Your update doesn't answer everything you were asked by brombeer

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment line

```
$randstring = $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters))];
```

Is overwriting each time you loop round.

```
$randstring .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters))];
```

Will add the character to the end of the string. The result will be a string of length ten

Comment: I want to add a '-', how do I do that?
RMXZ-MIGX-DYUJ-YVJM
Thank you very much